# Question regarding combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Hi im having some trouble understanding how I would go about answering this question.

Phone numbers consist of 8 digits. The first must be a 9. The second digit can be a 3, 4, 5 or 8. There are no restrictions on the remaining digits. How many different telephone numbers are possible?

This question is in The Addition and Multiplication Principles

Comment: Let's say for a moment the digits were just three. How would you do it?

Comment: You have $1$ option for the first digit, $4$ options for the second digit, and $10$ options for each one of the remaining $6$ digits. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Your first outcome is fixed, you can't change it. You have 4 options for the second outcome. You have 10 options for the remaining outcomes. Choice of each option is independent of the previous choices, so you can multiply these numbers. If this is still not clear, try drawing a tree for some small number of outcomes. Can you handle from here?